# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'isoweekday'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, attributeerror

I wrote a function that moves the date by specified number of working days in respect to the weekends and holidays. It works fine when I use it with scalar values however I have issue trying to use on the pandas DataFrame.
The function itself looks as follow:

```
def move_date_by_days(init_date, roll=1, nwd_key=None, hol_key=None):
    '''
    moves date by n-number of working days forward or backward
    init_date: date, initial caluclation date
    roll: integer, number of days to move forward (+) or backward (-)
    nwd_key: string that stands for currency iso code, it is a key in non_working_days dictionary
    hol_key: string that stands for currency iso code, it is a key in holidays dictonary
    return: date
    '''
    nwd = non_working_days.get(nwd_key, [])
    hol = holidays.get(hol_key,[])
    moved_date = init_date + datetime.timedelta(days=roll)
    if (moved_date.isoweekday() in nwd) or (moved_date in hol):
        if roll >= 0:
            moved_date=move_date_by_days(init_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1), roll=roll, nwd_key=nwd_key, hol_key=hol_key)
        else:
            moved_date=move_date_by_days(init_date + datetime.timedelta(days=-1), roll=roll, nwd_key=nwd_key, hol_key=hol_key)
    return moved_date
```

Now, I have DataFrame 'df' with the columns 'start_date' and 'end_date'

```
   start_date    end_date
0  2020-01-31  2020-04-30
1  2020-04-30  2020-07-31
2  2020-07-31  2020-10-31
3  2020-10-31  2020-11-28
```

and I would like to create the third column named 'fixing' that would be 2 working days before 'start_date'. I am trying this:

```
dates_table['fixing'] = move_date_by_days(self.dates_table['start_date'], -2, self.ccy, self.ccy)
```

but it returns `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'isoweekday'`

Please note the function works fine when I refer to scalar data of the DataFrame, for instance

```
d1 = s1.dates_table.iat[0,0]
move_date_by_days(d1, -2, 'pln', 'pln')
```

it returns what I have expected: `datetime.date(2020, 1, 29)`

Any hint how could I use the function on the whole column of the data frame, please?

Comment: This is the problem: `moved_date.isoweekday()`, try `moved_date.dt.isoweekday()`. But then you cannot use `or`. Try look up `np.where`.

Comment: Nope, `moved_date.dt.isoweekday()` did not work, (this dt refers to datetime I assume, right?) How would you use `np.where` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, why not use [`offsets.BDay`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.BDay.html) or [`offsets.CustomBusinessDay`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessDay.html) which takes a list of `holidays`:

```
df['fixing'] = df['start_date'] - pd.offsets.BDay(2)
df['fixing'] = df['start_date'] - pd.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(2, holidays=holidays['pln'])
```

[out]

```
  start_date   end_date     fixing
0 2020-01-31 2020-04-30 2020-01-29
1 2020-04-30 2020-07-31 2020-04-28
2 2020-07-31 2020-10-31 2020-07-29
3 2020-10-31 2020-11-28 2020-10-29
```

Comment: Well, I have written the whole module for rolling dates according to different convention (eod-of-month, following, modified-following etc.)  that are used in financials mainly as I could not find what I needed within in-built functions. Now I am trying to figure out why this function have issues with pandas. I know I could tackle this issue by calculating `fixing_date` outside the data frame and then merge it but I wonder if there is nicer solution or if I could modify somehow my own function to work with pandas too

Comment: did you try [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html)..? `df['fixing'] = df['start_date'].apply(lambda x: move_date_by_days(x, roll=-2, hol_key='pln', nwd_key='pln'))` ..?

Comment: Yes! This one works! Thank you very much, I have seen this lambda solution somwhere but I didn't know how to implement it in regards to my function. Thank you very much.

Comment: @halny glad it helped :)